# swift result builder for two different type of input and the same type of output

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui, protocols, dsl

This is the common function between ModelBuilder and StackModelBuilder in order to be called in the result builder functions

```
protocol Builder {
    func build() -> ViewFactory?
}

protocol ModelBuilder: Builder {
    var data: MerchDataSource? { get }
}

// Stack model builder is to build the container for the non-container builder

protocol StackModelBuilder: Builder {
    typealias StackBuilder = () -> [ViewFactory]
    
    var stackModel: StackModel { get }
    
    func generate(@ContainerBuilder _ builders: StackBuilder) -> ViewFactory
}

extension StackModelBuilder {
    func build() -> ViewFactory? {
        stackModel
    }
    
// this is to put any ModelBuilder result into a StackModelBuilder
    func generate(@ContainerBuilder _ builders: StackBuilder) -> ViewFactory{
        stackModel.stackables = builders()
        
        return stackModel
    }
}
```

Data source to Builders

```
protocol ActionableDataSource {
    var actionHandler: ((Any?) -> Void)? { get }
}

protocol MerchDataSource: ActionableDataSource {
    var displayModel: LabelModel { get }
}

struct TitleDataSource: DataSource {
    var displayModel: LabelModel
    var actionHandler: ((Any?) -> Void)?
}

struct ButtonDataSource: DataSource {
    var displayModel: LabelModel
    var actionHandler: ((Any?) -> Void)?
}

struct HeaderTitleBuilder: ModelBuilder {
    var data: DataSource?
    
    func build() -> ViewFactory? {
        return data.displayModel
    }
}

struct HeaderSubtitleBuilder: ModelBuilder {
    var data: DataSource?
    
    func build() -> ViewFactory? {
        return data.displayModel
    }
}

struct HeaderButtonBuilder: ModelBuilder {
    var data: DataSource?
    
    func build() -> ViewFactory? {
        return data.displayModel
    }
}
```

Result builder functions to call the ***build()*** on **StackModelBuilder** and **ModelBuilder** to produce the **ViewFactory**

```
@resultBuilder
struct ContainerBuilder {
//  static func buildBlock(_ builder: StackModelBuilder...) -> [ViewFactory] {
//      builder.compactMap{ $0.build() }
//  }

//  static func buildBlock(_ builder: [StackModelBuilder]...) -> [ViewFactory] {
//      builder.reduce([ViewFactory]()) {
//          $0 + $1.compactMap() { $0.build() }
//      }
//  }
    
    static func buildBlock(_ builder: Builder...) -> [ViewFactory] {
        [(builder as? Builder)?.build()].compactMap { $0 }
    }
    
    static func buildBlock(_ builder: [ViewFactory]...) -> [ViewFactory] {
        builder.flatMap { $0 }
    }
    
    static func buildBlock(_ builder: ViewFactory...) -> [ViewFactory] {
        builder
    }
    
    static func buildBlock() -> [ViewFactory] {
        []
    }
}
```

This is the **StackModelBuilder** is kind of container for **ModelBuilder**

```
struct HeaderTableRowCellBuilder: StackModelBuilder {
    private(set) var stackModel = StackModel(axis: .vertical, widthMetric: .fill, stackables: [])
}

struct HeaderTitleWithButtonBuilder: StackModelBuilder {
    private(set) var stackModel = StackModel(axis: .horizontal, alignmentMode: .content, stackables: [])
}
```

The final idea is to stack **StackModelBuilder** and **ModelBuilder** in this way.
But if uncomment the last line `HeaderSubtitleBuilder(data: TitleDataSource(displayModel: EUILabelDisplayModel()))`
I would get an error

> No exact matches in call to static method 'buildBlock'

```
let vf: [ViewFactory] = [
    HeaderTableRowCellBuilder().generate() {
        HeaderTitleWithButtonBuilder().generate() {
            HeaderTitleBuilder(data: TitleDataSource(displayModel: EUILabelDisplayModel()))
            HeaderButtonBuilder(data: ButtonDataSource(displayModel: EUILabelDisplayModel()))
        }
//      HeaderSubtitleBuilder(data: TitleDataSource(displayModel: EUILabelDisplayModel()))
    }
]
```

I confused what type do I miss in the result builder? There are only two type of input **StackModelBuilder** and **ModelBuilder** and only one **ViewFactory** output.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that I need to add

```
    static func buildExpression(_ builder: Builder) -> [ViewFactory] {
        [builder.build()].compactMap { $0 }
    }

    static func buildExpression(_ result: ViewFactory) -> [ViewFactory] {
        [result]
    }
```